# ImportError: No module named 'baseapi'

Tags: python

I can`t use the pyfcm module because of bellow error message.
How do I fix this error??

```
>>> from pyfcm import FCMNotification
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from pyfcm import FCMNotification
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyfcm\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .fcm import FCMNotification
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyfcm\fcm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from baseapi import BaseAPI
ImportError: No module named 'baseapi'
```

Comment: Install `baseapi`?

Comment: could you post your source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux, try running this command in the shell: `pip install baseapi`.

If you are using an IDE, look for a prompt asking if you want to install this package.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, The baseapi.py is already exist in the pyfcm folder.